# JList shows only a limited rowcount

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

My JList shows only a limited number of rows, but my listData-vector has over 70 items..

i use a jpanel for one list-item and add it to a vector -> after that -> mylist.setListData(theVector);

visibleRowCount can be set to 100 or 8, doesn't matter...

**EDIT: I have my JList within a JScrollPane, because i dragged it in my layout designer**

**EDIT2: Some code..**

```
private void initSubjectList() {
    try {
        Vector listData = new Vector();
        Vector<Subject> subjects = Subject.loadFromDB();
        for (Subject actSubject : subjects) {
            ListPanel listPanel = new ListPanel();
            listPanel.setSubject(actSubject);
            JLabel textLabel = new JLabel();
            // ... Some properties of my label...
            listPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            listPanel.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);

            listData.add(listPanel);
        }

        this.list_subjects.setListData(listData);
        this.list_subjects.setSelectedIndex(0);
        this.list_subjects.updateUI();
        initGradeList(grades, 0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        _parent.showError(ErrorPanel.TYPE_OKAY, ErrorPanel.TEXT_SQLEXCEPTION);
    }
```

Comment: Did you contain your JList in a ScrollPane?

Comment: yeah, i have my list in a scrollpane

Comment: Could you perhaps post some code, simplified so that it is just enough to demonstrate the problem? It is very difficult to say what you are doing wrong without seeing what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you are just not adding the myList to a layout allowing it to resize, so it too small. Or what exactly do you mean by not showing?
If you add it to the center of a BorderLayout for example, does it work then, at least if you resize the window?

Comment: Or if you just want it to be able to scroll without changing its size, see @Guillaume 's answer

Answer (score 3):

Put your JList in a JScrollPane:

```
JList list = new JList();
// ...
JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane(list);

// add scrollpane instead of list to hierarchy.
```

---

Here is a full working example:

```
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    protected static void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            data.add("Entry " + i);
        }
        JList list = new JList(data);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(8);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler without showing us code, all I can show you is how it is supposed to work. You must be doing something wrong but I can't guess it without seeing a code that reproduces your problem. Post an SSCCE http://sscce.org

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler note that the code you posted does not show the scrollpane you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing Height of your JList

Comment: Probably you can elaborate more this answer.